# VMWare cannot boot because Hypervisor role is enabled

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to run a Centos 7.6 inside a VMWare Workstation Pro but the VMWare fails to start because the Hyper-V and VMWare are not compatible. I have tried to disable Hyper-V but it's already disabled, I've tried to run all the commands that I've found on the Internet but none seems to work.

> VMware Workstation and Hyper-V are not compatible. Remove the Hyper-V
> role from the system before running VMware Workstation.

> Transport (VMDB) error -14: Pipe connection has been broken.

OS: Windows Server 2019

Edit: Virtualization was not possible because it was running on an already Virtualized machine.

Comment: How do you disable Hyper-V? Are you using the latest versions of Windows 10 and VMWare Workstation?

Comment: Make sure you are using VMware Workstation Pro V16 newest. It is supposed to co-exist.

Comment: Hello, I'm running it on a Windows Server 2019 and Workstation 16 lastest release. They cannot coexist. This is being done on a Clouding Server.

Comment: "They cannot coexist." - You are correct that is due to the fact the version of Windows that Windows Server 2019 does not have the compatibility feature that allows you to have both Hyper-V and VMWare installed at the same time.  Provide us with your current BCD.  What optional features (roles) do you have installed exactly?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment with this information.  Screenshots are best.

Comment: Do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line) to disable hyper-v at boot.  It is a BCD boot flag.   You can also copy your existing entry and have to option between the two.. even with a timeout if you want that..

Comment: Hyper-V can no longer disabled using `bcdedit` because *Virtualization-based Security* will make it run anyway. Disabling VBS is very non-trivial. // @DavidLópezDíaz Do you have any other Windows *Features* related to virtualization enabled, like *Virtual Machine Platform*?